# Calendar on HTML Input Text

Tags: html, input, calendar

I want a Calendar on a HTML Input Text.

I don't want HTML5 or other solutions.

I created a possible solution on this [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/n02jghab/1/)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://services.iperfect.net/js/IP_generalLib.js"></script>
</head>

<input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" alt="date" class="IP_calendar" title="d/m/Y">
```

But I'm looking for other alternatives with other styles.

Any suggestion?

Comment: have a search for a javascript date time calendar plugin - there are tons out there.  Also *don't want HTML5 or other solutions.*  What exactly do you want as this doesn't leave much

Comment: Yes, I don't want HTML5 or similar for the differents explorers that could have problems (ex: IE). With Javascript could be any problem?

Comment: Not if you pick a decent one - jquery ui has a good one but that would involve including 2 libraries and not sure it would be worth it if you didn't have jquery in your project already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not doing this (just checked it) :

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#start_datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#end_datepicker").datepicker();

  });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
  </head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
  <form action="sample.php" method="post">

Start Date: <input type="text" name="startdate" id="start_datepicker"/>
End Date: <input type="text" name="enddate" id="end_datepicker"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not searching for date range, but still valid ;)